# Is there a way to intercept stdout in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, stdout, nslog

I would like to intercept logging output in my swift project. For example, to redirect to a UITextView.

I've tried the general approach suggested [here](http://www.macosxguru.net/article.php?story=20031219101641977) but can't seem to make it work (see below).

EDIT: the log I want to tap into is coming from a static library I am using.

Here is my objective-c code:

```
UITextView *scrollview;

int stdoutwrite(void *inFD, const char *buffer, int size) {
    NSString    *tmp = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer length:size]  ;   // choose the best encoding for your app

    scrollview.text = NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", scrollview.text, tmp];

    return size ;
}

void redirectlog(UITextView *debugview) {
    scrollview = debugview;
    stdout->_write = stdoutwrite;
}
```

I'm calling `redirectlog` from my view controller.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Assertion failure in void _UIPerformResizeOfTextViewForTextContainer(NSLayoutManager *, UIView<NSTextContainerView> *, NSTextContainer *, NSUInteger)(), /SourceCache/UIFoundation/UIFoundation-376.14/UIFoundation/TextSystem/NSLayoutManager_Private.m:1547
2015-09-20 21:07:08.256 [380:84529] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'
```

Comment: Why not make a custom log function that goes to a text view?

Comment: @jtbandes because I want to intercept the log coming from a static library I'm using (should have mentioned that - edited question).

Comment: You can fix the "Only run on the main thread" exception easily by run it on main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is very clear. You can only update the text view in main thread. One simple way is dispatch it to main thread using `dispatch_async`.

```
int stdoutwrite(void *inFD, const char *buffer, int size) {
    NSString    *tmp = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer length:size]  ;   // choose the best encoding for your app

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        scrollview.text = NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", scrollview.text, tmp];
    });

    return size ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it would be that simple. I don't know why it wasn't executing on the main thread to begin with.

Comment: This redirects _every_ writes to stdout. Including writes made by background threads. So you have to make it thread-safe.

Comment: The question was about a solution in Swift. Is `NSString    *tmp = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer length:size]  ; ` allowed in Swift? This is Objective-C notation.